# Insertar 2 clave primaria de 2 tablas en una tercera que los va a relacional

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql, select, insert

Tengo 2 tablas.

Tabla empresa  y Tabla Categorías

Ambas tablas no serían relacionadas inicialmente, pero después necesitamos crear una tercera tabla.

Tabla categoria x empresa.

El query debe volcar todas las empresas y todas las categorías a la tercer tabla.

quedaría así el resultado.

empresa1  - categoría1
empresa1  - categoria2
empresa2  - categoria1
empresa2  - categoria2

... etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas hacer es lo que se conoce como producto cartesiano o `CROSS JOIN`, veamos un ejemplo básico:

```
create table empresas(
    id int,
    nombre varchar(255)
);

create table categorias(
    id int,
    nombre varchar(255)
);

insert into empresas(id, nombre) values (1, 'empresa1');
insert into empresas(id, nombre) values (2, 'empresa2');

insert into categorias(id, nombre) values (1, 'categoria1');
insert into categorias(id, nombre) values (2, 'categoria2');
```

Con un `CROSS JOIN` logramos hacer la combinación de cada registro de una tabla con cada registro de la otra:

```
select *
    from empresas e
    cross join categorias c
order by e.id;
```

El resultado final serían 2 x 2  = 4 registros, algo así:

```
id  nombre      id  nombre
--- ----------- --- -----------
1   empresa1    1   categoria1
1   empresa1    2   categoria2
2   empresa2    1   categoria1
2   empresa2    2   categoria2
```

Si vas a insertar esto en una tabla ternaria, simplemente deberías listar únicamente los `ids` de cada tabla.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table empresas(
    idempresas int PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre varchar(255)
);

create table categorias(
    idcategorias int PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre varchar(255)
);

create table EmpresaxCategoria(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    idempresas int,
    idcategorias int,
    nombre varchar(255)
);
declare @UltimoIdInsertadoEmpresa int
declare @UltimoIdInsertadoCategorias int

insert into empresas(id, nombre) values (1, 'empresa1');
SET @UltimoIdInsertadoEmpresa = last_insert_id()

insert into categorias(id, nombre) values (1, 'categoria1');
SET @UltimoIdInsertadoCategorias = last_insert_id()

insert into EmpresaxCategoria (idempresas, idcategorias) values (@UltimoIdInsertadoEmpresa, @UltimoIdInsertadoCategoria)
```

Y ésta sería la consulta que te traiga tus resultados

```
    select empresas.Nombre, categorias.nombre from EmpresasxCategoria
inner join empresas
on EmpresasxCategoria.idempresas = empresas.idempresas = 
inner join categorias 
on EmpresasxCategoria.idcategorias = categorias.idcategorias
```